# How to make cards scroll vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

What is the best way to create a vertical scroll when one card is stacked on top of another, similar to the example shown in the link below?

[Link here](https://pin.it/1sHYa10)

I've searched some information and examples but haven't found anything.

If anyone knows or has examples, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use margin-top 'minus'px

```css
.card_wrap{
  width:200px;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  padding:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background:beige;
}
.card_wrap .card{  
  background:pink;
  padding:1rem;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;  
  margin-top:-50px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px gray;
  border-radius:8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.card_wrap .card:hover{
  background:skyblue;
}
.card_wrap .card:hover + .card{
  margin-top:0;
}
.card_wrap .card:nth-of-type(1){
  margin-top:0;
]
```

```html
<div class="card_wrap">
  <div class="card">card1</div>
  <div class="card">card2</div>
  <div class="card">card3</div>
  <div class="card">card4</div>
  <div class="card">card5</div>
  <div class="card">card6</div>
  <div class="card">card7</div>
  <div class="card">card8</div>
  <div class="card">card9</div>
  <div class="card">card10</div>
  <div class="card">card11</div>
  <div class="card">card12</div>
  <div class="card">card13</div>
  <div class="card">card14</div>
  <div class="card">card15</div>
  <div class="card">card16</div>
  <div class="card">card17</div>
  <div class="card">card18</div>
  <div class="card">card19</div>
  <div class="card">card20</div>
  <div class="card">card21</div>
  <div class="card">card22</div>
  <div class="card">card23</div>
  <div class="card">card24</div>
  <div class="card">card25</div>
  <div class="card">card26</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning calculated dynamically in Javascript.

```js
let topc = 30
Array.from(document.querySelector('.cards').children).forEach(c => {
  hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
  c.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(' + hue + ', 50%, 50%)'
  c.style.top = topc + 'px'
  topc += 50
})
```

```css
.cards {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
.cards>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id quam eu ipsum viverra gravida.</div>
  <div>Nunc feugiat hendrerit leo, at finibus purus efficitur et. Sed vel semper libero.</div>
  <div>Pellentesque feugiat, tortor sollicitudin tristique elementum, diam lacus mattis libero, eu tincidunt purus ligula nec magna.</div>
  <div>Sed at vulputate enim, ut rutrum nulla. Curabitur fermentum a dolor et cursus.</div>
  <div>Nunc eleifend nec sem ac suscipit. Curabitur ut viverra mi. Nam lacinia sem lacus.</div>
  <div>Integer aliquet ipsum in eros molestie maximus. Praesent erat lacus, suscipit ut rutrum eu, consequat eget ex.</div>
  <div>tMaecenas interdum nunc vitae risus euismod gravida. Pellentesque ultrices pharetra malesuada.he</div>
  <div>Pellentesque lacus magna, hendrerit mollis odio in, volutpat consectetur elit. Nulla facilisi.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id quam eu ipsum viverra gravida.</div>
  <div>Nunc feugiat hendrerit leo, at finibus purus efficitur et. Sed vel semper libero.</div>
  <div>Pellentesque feugiat, tortor sollicitudin tristique elementum, diam lacus mattis libero, eu tincidunt purus ligula nec magna.</div>
  <div>Sed at vulputate enim, ut rutrum nulla. Curabitur fermentum a dolor et cursus.</div>
  <div>Nunc eleifend nec sem ac suscipit. Curabitur ut viverra mi. Nam lacinia sem lacus.</div>
  <div>Integer aliquet ipsum in eros molestie maximus. Praesent erat lacus, suscipit ut rutrum eu, consequat eget ex.</div>
  <div>tMaecenas interdum nunc vitae risus euismod gravida. Pellentesque ultrices pharetra malesuada.he</div>
  <div>Pellentesque lacus magna, hendrerit mollis odio in, volutpat consectetur elit. Nulla facilisi.</div>
</div>
```